# Docker list container - Gitlab Runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab Runner on my VPS with gitlabrunner running in a container.

I would like to know if there is a command to list all containers **of the first level**.

When my runner takes a job and I enter `docker ps` I see the **runner container** listed.
But it's supposed to be running in my first docker container.

How can docker differentiate this ?

[image: Output of <code>docker ps</code>]

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` for my runner :

```
version: "3"
services:
  runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/adrien/runners/coretest/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and my `config.toml` :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "My Docker Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "<my-token>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Comment: I binded my docker volumes but is there a way to see which docker container is running inside an other one ?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the docker runner, which mounts the docker sock in the runner, which lets the runner run new containers on the host's docker daemon. The CI job won't run in the `coretest_runner_1` container; the job of the `coretest_runner_1` container is to accept jobs from Gitlab, and then to manipulate the host's Docker daemon to spin up containers to run those CI jobs in. Your `runner` container is a sibling of your `coretest_runner_1` container, not a child of it.

If you want the CI job to run in the `coretest_runner_1` container, you will need to change your runners.executor to "shell", so that it runs in the same context as the gitlab-runner daemon (which is in the container) (see the [executors doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/)).

Be aware that this means that your jobs don't get clean, isolated state, and could conflict with each other.

Comment: Do I need to change something for docker binding, can I use shell executor when running GitLab Runner in a container ? I changed my executor from `docker` to `shell` but now I get `docker: command not found` during my job :/